# MARKed packets not routing as expected

Tags: networking, iptables, routing-table

UPDATE: Solution: I should have been using the OUTPUT chain - not the PREROUTING chain. This example still doesn't work but I'll update it soon.

This seems to me like it should work. I move all the routing rules from the main table to table 4 and then MARK and direct packets destined to port 80/443 to table 4. I would expect port 80 to work the same as if I had done nothing but gethostbyname just fails?

```
#!/bin/bash -x
#
# Reset/Flush iptables
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

# Reset/Flush table 4
ip route flush table 4

# move all routing rules from the main table to table 4
ip route show table main | grep -v linkdown |
while read ROUTE
do
  ip route add table 4 $ROUTE
  ip route del table main $ROUTE
done

# MARK all HTTP(S) destination packets with a 4
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80  -j MARK --set-mark 4
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j MARK --set-mark 4
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 53  -j MARK --set-mark 4

# packets marked as 4 find their routes via table 4
ip rule add fwmark 4 table 4
ip route flush cache
```

Comment: Your iptables rules won't be reached, because there's no route in main table. Because they won't execute, they'll never set the mark telling to use table 4. So you don't have any route... Now could you tell what problem you actually intend to solve with all this?

Comment: So a route has to be found before pre-routing executes? That seems like the wrong thing to do since the rule could do something to change the routing (like in my case)?

Comment: As for the problem: I need to do something like a transparent proxy through a TUN device for all ports other than HTTP, DNS. So that means that if an app sends something to foo.com:22 it needs to actually go to a TUN device and my proxy app needs to really send it to foo.com:22. So not shown above is the default rule in main that sends everything to my TUN device. So I do have a route in the main table but it doesn't help.

Comment: Okay. I see now. I should have been using the OUTPUT chain - not the PREROUTING chain.

Comment: I tried it too before answering. No change. If there's no route, the PREROUTING won't be used, nor the OUTPUT. You should invest into iptables' TPROXY and see what you can do with it. Or you can just keep the main routes, thus iptables should trigger, set the fwmark and in the end the table 4 will be used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iptables (and/or netfilter) has [various hooks](http://inai.de/images/nf-packet-flow.png) in the routing stack. When a packet passes a certain step in the routing stack, if there's an iptables hook there, iptables' hook is run. Of course, if the packet doesn't reach such step, no iptables hook is run. If there's "no route to host" the routing stack gives up earlier and doesn't reach those steps. That's what's happening in your example after you deleted the (main table's) routes and left a routing table that depends on iptables to be ever used. That's a chicken-and-eggs problem, but it doesn't need to be done all this way. You just need a route, any route, so your rules will trigger and change this route.

I ran your script, and got with my settings:

```
# ip route
(nothing)
# ip route show table 4
default via 10.0.3.1 dev eth0 
10.0.3.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.3.66
```

Added the OUTPUT rules:

```
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x4/0xffffffff
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x4/0xffffffff
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x4/0xffffffff
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x4/0xffffffff
```

Nothing works.

Added the LAN route and a fake, wrong gateway 10.0.3.9 which doesn't exist:

```
# ip route
default via 10.0.3.9 dev eth0 
10.0.3.0/24 dev eth0 scope link 

# ip neigh flush dev eth0
# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1006ms
# ip neigh
10.0.3.9 dev eth0  FAILED
# ip neigh del 10.0.3.9 dev eth0
# dig +short @8.8.8.8 google.com.
172.217.22.142
# ip neigh
10.0.3.1 dev eth0 lladdr fe:d6:50:75:27:c9 REACHABLE
```

Notice that *now* the route from table 4 was used. But it needed a working route first ("on the paper" even if not really working), else the routing decision alone would have prevented the OUTPUT rule to be used at all. You can see it with `iptables-save -c` to see counters.

Comment: Exactly right. Changing to OUTPUT solved my problem because I did have an address there. I didn't show it in my question because I was trying to make a smaller example of the problem and did not imagine this detail was relevant. Thanks!